# Is it possible to submit original graphics for the site's appearence?

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion

I don't know the site's policy regarding graphics. As a part-time designer, I think the site would be much more appealing with a nice banner (header) on top of the page. Is it possible to submit to the community some ideas for the graphics, or are these problems dealt with only at admin level (or higher)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current design of the site is the standard SE design for "beta" sites. 
[All the sites in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) have this design.

When a site reaches a certain critical mass it "graduates." As part of this process the site gets its own design. This design is done by SE staff with some community input.

To get an idea of this process see for example a [relevant thread on a site that already graduated](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/891/updated-april-14-design-for-academia-se).

To answer your questions directly: Thank you for volunteering to do this, but for all I know SE will not change the look of our site before it has become larger. When this happens SE will take care of it, and then they might be open to suggestions.

Comment: Looking here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators I see that we have 1.5 question per day, but need to get up to 10 questions per day for graduation.  Still some time to go!

Comment: Indeed. Although as far as I understand the 10 is not a strict threshold. It seems some sites  have been launched at about 7 recently. But either way it is some way to go.